# Reaching unexpected objc breakpoint with method __Block_byref_object_copy_

Tags: objective-c, debugging, compilation, internals

I'm using lldb to debug objc based service. several breakpoints (which is set
have been placed in the code, and I see that one of them is reached unexpectedly according to the stack trace.

The method encapsulating this breakpoint shouldn't have called but I still see it in stack trace (file1.mm:97) although it seems like the code isn't being execute there.

I suspect that objc internal method `__Block_byref_object_copy_` is responsible for copying the block of code which involves both caller and callee methods (MyClass from the upper frame in the stack and the method in file1.mm:97).

While copying the debugger probably thinks that it reach this line for execution and stop there, where in fact it's only for copying the code block which involves those 2 methods.

Perhaps anybody can support this claim or provide additional explanation of why am I getting this breakpoint where it shouldn't occur ?

```
  * frame #0: 0x0000000107e03ce0 MyLib`::__Block_byref_object_copy_((null)=0x00007fda19a86b30, (null)=0x00007ffeea7f3bd0) at file1.mm:97:27
    frame #1: 0x00007fff7de6bb78 libsystem_blocks.dylib`_Block_object_assign + 325
    frame #2: 0x0000000107dd960a MyLib`::__copy_helper_block_ea8_32r((null)=0x00007fda19a86540, (null)=0x00007ffeea7f3ba8) at file2.mm:47:55
    frame #3: 0x00007fff7de6b9f3 libsystem_blocks.dylib`_Block_copy + 104
    frame #4: 0x00007fff7c64e1e8 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_setProperty_atomic_copy + 53
    frame #5: 0x00007fff5411d16b Foundation`-[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:orArguments:count:methodSignature:selector:withProxy:] + 1885
    frame #6: 0x00007fff54168508 Foundation`-[NSXPCConnection _sendSelector:withProxy:arg1:arg2:] + 125
    frame #7: 0x00007fff54168485 Foundation`_NSXPCDistantObjectSimpleMessageSend2 + 46
    frame #8: 0x0000000107e0520e MyLib`::-[MyClass func:withVar0:Var1:Var2:withError:](self=0x00007fda17c2cb50, _cmd="funcWithVar0:Var1:Var2:Var3:withError:", var0="aaa", var1=0x0000000000000000, var2="bbb", var3=0x00007fda17d41dd0, err=0x00007ffeea7f4258) at MyClass.mm:196:5
```

UPDATE:

thanks to the comments below, it happen that if I set breakpoint according to file and line, it gives me 3 locations (!?)

breakpoint set --file myfile.mm --line 97

now when I list my breakpoints, it give me 2 breakpoints that aren't related to the actual method which wraps the file, besides the expected breakpoint.

```
  3.2: where = my class`::__Block_byref_object_copy_() + 16 at myfile:97:27, address = 0x0000000107e03ce0, unresolved, hit count = 0 
  3.3: where = myclass `::__Block_byref_object_dispose_() + 16 at myfile:97:27, address = 0x0000000107e03d40, unresolved, hit count = 0
```

Comment: You tried the usual *Clean build folder* and also holding down alt and *Clean build folder* ...

Comment: ... and also you checked your *symbolic breakpoints*

Comment: I've deleted the entire DerivedData folder, and the problem still occur. when the breakpoint occur I see `    frame #0: 0x000000010b147ca0 myClass`::__Block_byref_object_copy_((null)=0x00007f8abc3664f0, (null)=0x00007ffee763abd0) at myfile:97:27` but the but the code at myfile:97 is not wrapped by method __Block_byref_object_copy_

Comment: You could've set some weird symbolic or runtime breakpoint that gets triggered?

Comment: @skaak, you where right, it did set some expected locations when setting the breakpoint... do you know why ?

Comment: Have you done some sanity checks by printing to the console to be sure what is getting called and what is not?

Comment: @zohar81 - not sure. I think if you look at the disassembly of the code and the detail of the breakpoint it will make sense. Maybe the way to solve your problem is not to unravel this breakpoint but rather set a new one a bit differently?

Comment: very hard to tell without a line of code. Because the debugger may be total correct and some syntax sugar is tricking you blind. maybe a leak spreading fun while debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, more an illustration ...

```
unsigned fn ( void )
{
    return 3;    // Set bp here and see what happens
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
        unsigned int x = 0;

        x = 1;
        x = 2;
        x = 3;

        if ( x >= 0 )
        {
            switch ( 5 )
            {
                case 1 : x = 4; break;
                case 2 : x = 4; break;   // Set bp here - it will trigger!!!!
                case 3 : x = 4; break;
                case 4 : x = 4; break;
                case 5 : x = 4; break;   // Set bp here and see what happens
                case 6 : x = 4; break;
                case 7 : x = 4; break;
                default : x = 4; break;
                    
            }
        }

        __block unsigned y;

        void ( ^ b1 )( void ) = ^ {

            y = fn();

        };

        void ( ^ b2 )( void ) = ^ {

            b1();

        };

        if ( YES )
        {
            b2();
        }

        NSLog ( @"x = %u y = %u", x, y );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Without going into too much detail, note that most of the code above will be optimised away. The compiler will optimise `for` loops and `switches` aggressively and will optimise superfluous assignments and checks (e.g. x >= 0 for unsigned x) away. Above even the blocks gets inlined and you end up with what appears to be very strange behaviour. I think the blocks here are relevant to your specific problem?

If you optimise then the first breakpoint indicated in the code does not get triggered as the blocks all get inlined (I think as I did not look at the disassembly). Likewise the third one does get triggered, but because of optimisation in the strangest of places. Really, a large part of the code gets reduced into a single assignment and the compiler does not really know where to stick it so when that bp is triggered it looks as if it is in the strangest and most disconnected place possible.

Finally, even the second (!!!) one will trigger. That code should never execute but since it all collapse due to optimisation you can even get it to trigger.

So I would not be too perplexed about what triggers your bp ...

I mean, above I just proved that 2 == 5 if I take the bp seriously. And that is not even variable but constant 2 == 5!!! Quite amusing ...

Comment: I am having too much fun with this example - set e.g. a bp on any of the first few assignments and see where it takes you ... breakpoints and compilter optimisations together combine to deliver buckets full of hilarity. But lets get serious - you can not take them seriously.